# How do I add a 'DropShadow' effect to a control (box/grid) in a Windows Store App using XAML/C#?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store, dropshadow

I have a Windows Store App. I'm looking to add a Drop Shadow effect. I've considered using a Gradiented border, but I can't seem to get it to look right. I've tried setting the Border's `BorderBrush` to a [`LinearGradientBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br210108), going from the background color to black, but it seems... out of place, is the best way to put it. Is there a better way to be doing this? Is there a better `Gradient` I should be using? (Non-linear?)

I think based on some suggestions that people had using CSS that going to a dark grey instead of black is the better option, so I will be toying around with that in the meantime.

What constitutes the 'standard' CSS Drop Shadow? Are there specific alpha levels that it goes up to? Is it a linear gradient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appear to have figured it out.

Note: This answer is for a Top-And-Bottom only drop shadow, not all the way around.

I created a `Border`, as described in the question, and created a `BorderBrush` as defined below:

```
<Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0,5,0,5">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".5,0" EndPoint=".5,1">
            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset=".03"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset=".98"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
     </Border.BorderBrush>
</Border>
```

Strangely enough, in order to get a similar effect on the top and bottom, I had to make the bottom `GradientStop` closer to the edge than the top. I'm not sure why that is.

What this will do is if you have content on a `Blue` border, it will create a top drop shadow stripe and a bottom drop shadow stripe. It works pretty well for me right now.

The `StartPoint`/`Endpoint` define a point at the top center and bottom center (halfway in on x, 0 y, then halfway in on x, 1 y). For, say, one on the left and right side, all you'd have to do is change the `StartPoint` and `EndPoints` to: `StartPoint="0,.5" EndPoint="1,.5"`.

I'm not sure how to change it for all the way around. I think it may likely require going from the center `(.5,.5)` to a corner `(0,0)`, but I haven't gotten this to work yet.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Up to DropShadow effect besides using brush, we could draw by ourselves.

```
<Grid Width="100" Height="100">
    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Margin="5" RadiusX="7" RadiusY="7" Opacity="0.3"/>
    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Margin="4" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8" Opacity="0.25"/>
    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Margin="3" RadiusX="9" RadiusY="9" Opacity="0.2"/>
    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Margin="2" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Opacity="0.15"/>
    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Margin="1" RadiusX="11" RadiusY="11" Opacity="0.1"/>
    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Margin="0" RadiusX="12" RadiusY="12" Opacity="0.05"/>
</Grid>
```

This will create a Grid with black drop-shadow around.